# How to automate test case generation (complete & running test case not just boilerplate) of an angular app?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, automated-tests, karma-jasmine, gulp-karma

I am a lazy programmer. I want to automate test case generation of my large angularjs app. Currently, I am using jasmine and karma.

What I want is, to extract the module, components and methods dynamically and create a test case which should pass.

Basically, I want to add it to 'watch' so that as I am coding, the test cases get generated and get passed/failed based on the status the code and supplied mock data.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a generator for jasmine angular controller tests?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857701/is-there-a-generator-for-jasmine-angular-controller-tests)

Comment: Its not the duplicate. I am not looking for boilerplate test. I need the fully functional and running test case. All the needed variables and methods are already present in the codebase. Its just a new file with some different syntax. Only thing extra is, mock data that is a next step.

Comment: The answers cover this to the point whether it is possible, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32646994/3731501) for instance. There's nothing better, to my knowledge. Otherwise a lot of people would lose their jobs.

Comment: I already tried tleaf, it generates a boilerplate for each controller you run it for. I am going to try to develop a generator as per my need, will post if I get anywhere with this.

Comment: Good luck with that, consider pinging me with @ if you will come up with the answer, it would be interesting to see. The task looks quite ambitious, because it will require to stub the entire `angular` API, also the code should likely run with Phantomjs or Jsdom to probe the methods which are defined inside functions.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thing and it does a lot of good job:

```
npm i ai-test-gen-angular
export OPENAI_API_KEY=somekey
node ./node_modules/ai-test-gen-angular/index.js "relative/path/to/service/or/somecomponent.component.ts" "relative/path/to/tsconfig.json"
```

Answer was shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77354100/22796169)